# Does dnf have an equivalent to apt's "build-dep"

Tags: linux, apt, package-management, dependencies, dnf

something like

```
sudo apt build-dep apache
```

Supposedly installs all the dependencies needed to build `apache` from source (I've never used it before).

Is there an equivalent command for the `dnf` package manager?

Comment: Tip: [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is, it's

```
sudo dnf builddep httpd
```

`builddep` is a `dnf` plugin, so it's not documented in the `dnf` manpage. It is [described in the DNF plugin documentation](http://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builddep.html), and it has its own manpage, `dnf.plugin.builddep(8)`.